# Initial Xamarin

Tags: ios, xcode, mobile, xamarin

I have an issue when building for iOS in Xamarin Studio:

I open Xamarin Studio and create a Single Project View App for IOS, I then run the project, but the project does not load onto the simulator all I get is the message

> "Waiting for the debugger to connect to the iOS Simulator".

I have xcode installed on the machine.

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Comment: Does it work if you launch a simulator through Xcode?

Answer (score 2):

Try launching XCode directly - often after an update XCode will require you to accept a new EULA before it will launch, which can prevent other apps from launching XCode (or its components) automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Other options to fix this issue:

- You could also try to `Reset Content and Settings...` on the actual simulator menu, then build again.
- Re adding the simulator: Open Xcode >  ⌘⇧2 to open Devices > Select the simulator device you are trying to use > Right click and delete it > Then add it again, bottom left `+` button.

If this doesnt work try checking for any errors in Console.app when building to the simulator.

Answer (score 0):

I always ran into issues when there're different Xamarin versions on the MAC and the Windows PC. Also cleaning the solution, re-connecting the MAC and rebuild the project is always worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

First of all open iOS Simulator after that clean your project solution and project, then run your project it works for me.